# Simulated low energy electron diffraction (LEED) patterns

Tags: software, vasp, diffraction, electron-diffraction

What modern software supports the generation of LEED patterns?  It seems most LEED simulation packages are quite old and do not work on modern hardware.  Is there something that prevents common software like VASP from simulating LEED or is it just not implemented?

Comment: I added the electron-diffraction tag (which should have been there anyway). This will hopefully bump the question up and help you get an answer quickly.

Comment: I have emailed Franziska Hess for an answer, because she answered [this LEED question on our site](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/search?q=LEED) before, but got an automated response saying she'll be back on August 12th. You may be able to ask uhoh for an answer here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55190383#55190383

Comment: just fyi [Determining if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619) currently has a `+200` bounty in Math SE

Comment: also fyi bounties have [24 hour grace periods](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/877/12102) during which they are invisible to others but still awardable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer, somewhat link-only...

The website of Prof. Michel A. Van Hove, Emeritus Chair Professor in Physics and Ex-Director, Institute of Computational and Theoretical Studies, Hong Kong Baptist University is http://www.icts.hkbu.edu.hk/vanhove/#Download_software

There you can see links to many LEED simulation packages. See also [publications](http://www.icts.hkbu.edu.hk/vanhove/#Pubs)

Professor Van Hove is author of many things, including these books:

- [Surface Crystallography by LEED: Theory, Computation and Structural Results](https://books.google.com/books?id=qC_vCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=van+hove+leed&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKn6uohIzrAhULkJQKHSxnDlAQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=van%20hove%20leed&f=false)
- [Low-Energy Electron Diffraction: Experiment, Theory and Surface Structure Determination](https://books.google.com/books?id=bWLyCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=van+hove+leed&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKn6uohIzrAhULkJQKHSxnDlAQ6AEwAXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=van%20hove%20leed&f=false)

---

> What modern software supports the generation of LEED patterns?

I would like to know the answer to this as well!

If you only need the positions of possible LEED spots but no intensity information, then on that page you can find

> Graphical LEED pattern simulator: [LEEDpat](http://www.fhi-berlin.mpg.de/KHsoftware/LEEDpat/index.html)

which is old but I believe still runs on modern Windows OS. It is a little hard to run if you are not familiar with the five 2D Bravais lattices and 17 wallpaper groups (cf. [Number of possible rotational domains of one 2D lattice on top of another?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3566248/284619))

I've asked [Overview of how self-consistent dynamical low-energy electron diffraction simulations are performed](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/527/201) It received the usual answer which is something like *find someone who does it and collaborate with them*, but I feel it's time to make a modern package and incorporate the older programs compilable codes into some modern environment like Python.

The current answer says "I'm talking several 100k lines of code" but I'm sure much of that can be replace with modern numerical libraries now.

Comment: @NikeDattani if all they really need is LEEDpat, then the link to it will be an answer. If they need relative intensities of the spots and their variation with beam energy (I-V LEED (intensity vs. voltage)) then there may be no modern packages in existence until one gets written.